# How to use Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications with Net 7

Tags: .net, visual-studio

The following code is not compiling with net 7

```
  var builder = new ToastContentBuilder()
               .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
               .AddText("Some text")
               .AddButton(new ToastButton()
                   .SetContent("Archive")
                   .AddArgument("action", "archive"));
            builder.Show();
```

The Show method is not available. I have the following in the csproj file

```
   <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: Probably your project is not UWP. Show() method is available in UWP applications: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/2d608fdb831380fb2827ec18d24efa59c9ff0ef2/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications/Toasts/Builder/ToastContentBuilder.cs#L412

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I worked it out, you have to specify the TargetFramework as below

```
 <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Comment: Or whatever version of the SDK you are targeting

Comment: You need to specify the *Windows* SDK you're targeting. This is documented at [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance)